# Conveying the ironic use of 'nice try'

Tags: anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, ironie

The conversational phrase *nice try* can be used ironically when someone is trying to cheat you or play a trick on you. For instance.

> -"You'll double your money in a month if you invest in this scheme."
>
> -"Hah! Nice try, pal, but I wasn't born yesterday."

> -"Tu vas doubler votre argent en un mois si tu investis dans ce plan."
>
> -"Hah ! **Bien essayé**, mon pote, mais je ne suis pas né de la dernière pluie."

Does *bien essayé* convey the ironic meaning of *nice try*?

Comment: I don't see any irony in "nice try" nor in "bien essayé".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ***bien essayé !*** or I believe the better ***bien tenté !*** convey that meaning.

> [*Bien tenté mon gars, mais t'as fait un flop !*](https://www.senscritique.com/liste/bien_tente_mon_gars_mais_t_as_fait_un_flop/7851)

***Bien joué !*** can also be used ironically in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Oui, comme on dit [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52222/26366), « [bien essayé](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/try/620008) » (Larousse en ligne anglais-français le donne pour « good try »). J'aime bien aussi « (un) bel effort » que je dirais assez naturellement dans ce genre de contexte...